# ASP.NET inner directory virtual path root

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, virtual-directory

I have two separate web applications named MainWeb and Reports. I want to deploy them this way: there would be one virtual application for MainWeb, pointed, for instance, to *c:\inetpub\www\mainweb*.

The Reports application I would like to deploy in a subdirectory of main web, so that it is at *c:\inetpub\www\mainweb\reports*.

Thus I can combine the two which are logically coupled but I want to have them in separate projects for easy manipulation.

The problem is, in my Reports project I use constructs like `~/Style/Whatever.css` which works fine when running standalone Reports application but when using as subdirectory in main web, it resolves to *http://localhost/Style/Whatever.css* though I would need it to resolve to *http://localhost/**reports**/Style/Whatever.css*.

So the question is, is it possible to handle this situation, maybe some way to modify the behavior of `~` in nested web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a webby guy, but how about a shortcut to the real folder in reports?

Comment: Actually, this is the way I had to do it at last. I had to create another Reports directory in Reports project and put all stuff in there. Then in main web I created link to that Reports directory and removed virtual application for Reports project. Then I made all stuff in Reports project point to `~/Reports/Something.xxx` instead of `~/Someting.xxx`. Thus I can use reports both in main web and standalone. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

hm, I have similar situation and I am not sure what's your problem, VirtualPathUtility and server control resolves ~ to current web application root.

But maybe you can put Virtual Path in Properties/Web section of your Reports application directory for localhost, [picture here](http://screencast.com/t/kK4DBV9RRWh0)

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion, but this would not work for me as I'm using IIS and also it would not work when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different ways I've solved this problem before:

1. Move your style references from the "Report" app up to the "MainWeb" app.  This way your "~" url references will still work.  You can use another virtual directory to link your resource folders in under the root if you don't want to move the actual files.
2. Create a static helper property called "ApplicationPath" that will return either "~/" or "~/Reports" depending on where it is being hosted.  Then you can just use this property to return the correct url for your resource when you are building the HTML.
3. Use embedded resources.  With the embedded resources, the URL is automatically generated for you so you don't have to worry about the paths.

Comment: Hi. 1. would break the reason why i'm doing the separation. 2. there are places where i wouldn't know ho to use it, e.g. referencing controls: `<%@ Register TagName="Ctl" TagPrefix="control" Src="~/Ctl.ascx" %>`. 3. although I was talking about css, I didn't mention that is not the only problem, but masterpage, control referencing etc., sorry for that. Thanks for suggestions, though.